# List box conversion to array int

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, listbox, int

I'm trying to convert a listbox to an array:

```
var modarray = listBox1.Items.Cast<String>().ToArray();
```

but then I also need to use an int array so I tried the following:

```
int[] arr = modarray.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

I get an error that suggests that is not possible to convert the array. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
int[] arr = modarray.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

This will use the `int.Parse()` method for each of the strings in the original array to create a new integer array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
int[] arr = modarray.Select(I => Convert.ToInt32(I)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

`.Cast<int>()` is like `foreach (var i in list) yield return (int)i;`

Which if your items are strings underneath will fail.

I believe you need: `int[] arr = modarray.Select(s => Int32.Parse(s)).ToArray();`